# How to re-write Complex Equations using the Argument Function?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

According to wolfram alpha, we can rewrite the expression $\left(1+it\right)^{x}$ as mentioned below. How would one go about deriving the following equations by hand? ($x,t\inℝ$)

$\Re\left(\left(1+it\right)^{x}\right)=\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}\cos\left(x\arg\left(1+it\right)\right)$

$\Im\left(\left(1+it\right)^{x}\right)=\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}}\sin\left(x\arg\left(1+it\right)\right)$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar/exponential notation, if $z=re^{i \theta}$, then
$$z^x = r^x e^{i \theta x} = r^x \Big( \cos(\theta x) + i \cdot \sin(\theta x) \Big)$$
So the magnitude is raised to the $x$ power, and the argument is multiplied by $x$. In this ntoation, $\theta = \mathrm{arg}(z)$, so that explains the $\cos(x \mathrm{arg}(1+it))$ part of your question. For the other part, just notice that
the norm of $1+it$ is $|1+it| = \sqrt{1+t^2}$, and raising this to the $x$ power gives the $(1+t^2)^{x/2}$ part.